# Angular UI Router not executing controller code when change state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I'm developing an Ionic app, using a side menu. But the change of states is not working as I want it to.

This is my parent-child relationship defined in my `$stateProvider` in the `app.js` file:

```
  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
      .state('app', {
        url: "/app",
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
        controller: 'AppCtrl'
      })
      .state('app.home', {
        url: "/home",
        views: {
          'menuContent':{
            templateUrl: "templates/home.html",
            controller: 'AppCtrl'
          }
        }
      })
      .state('app.map', {
          url: "/map",
          views: {
              'menuContent':{
                  templateUrl: "templates/map.html",
                  controller: 'MapCtrl'
              }
          }
      });
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/home');
});
```

**These are the steps to follow:**

When I click in the area element defined in the `home.html` template:

```
       <area id="ImgMap" shape="poly" coords="456,326,521,69,274,10,259,91,290,216,388,326"
           ng-click="loadMap(0)" ui-sref="app.mapa" ui-sref-opts="{ reload: true }" title="Map" alt="Map"/>
       //I've also tried with href='#/app/map'
```

the app goes to the `app.map` state, loads the `map.html` template and executes correctly the `MapCtrl` controller code.

Then, if I go back to the `home.html` page through the side menu (code as follow):

```
 <ion-side-menus>
  <ion-pane ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive nav-title-slide-ios7">
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view name="menuContent" animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-pane>
  <ion-side-menu side="left" >
    <ion-content class="mymenu">
      <div id="menu-list">
        <ion-list class="list">
          <ion-item item-type="item-icon-left" nav-clear menu-close href="#/app/home">
            <i class="icon ion-home"></i><span>Home</span>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
      </div>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

And I click again in the area element defined in the `home.html` page, just like the first. Only this time it navigates correctly to the `map` page, but the controller `MapCtrl` doesn't execute its code, so I can't reload the map info if needed.

**So, in resume**. From my `home` state I go to the `map` state, and everything executes correctly. But if I go back to the `home` state and repeat the process, the controller of the `map` state doesn't execute its code this time.

**What am I doing wrong?**

I've tried different solutions, trying to use `template` option instead of `templateUrl`, force the change and reload of state with `$state.go()`, etc... but none of them seems to work as I expect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you are facing is obvious. That occurs because your controller is loaded only once in Single Page Application. However, in ionic there is a quick fix. You can keep the codes that you want to run in each call of your controller inside the `ionicViewBeforeEnter`.

```
app.module('YourAppName').controller('MapCtrl ',function(){
    $scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function(){ 
      //all your code you want to reinitialize goes here.
    });
});
```

Comment: Alternatively you can disable cache in state definition

Comment: @MuliYulzary apparantly that doesn't reload the controller :/

Comment: @AlexRumbaNicked thank you so much! Your solution covered my needs perfectly!